# Creating new file from assets folder, isDirectory() returns false

Tags: android, file, directory, assets

When I call this :

```
File directory = new File("file:///android_asset/");
```

then this :

```
directory.isDirectory()
```

Always returns `false`.
Am I doing something wrong here ?
(Sorry if it is a dumb question)

**Edit:**
I store several images in the `assets` folder and I wanted to load them in my app (like an image gallery).

Comment: You cannot use File for files in assets. Instead use AssetManager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call

```
directory.mkdirs();
```

after you created the `File` object

**Edit:** 
in your case try to change file url as below:

```
new File("/mnt/external_sd/");
```

or find the true path by looking it in eclipse File explorer.. do not start it with `file://`

Comment: but I have several images in my `assets` folder, and I wanted to get the file paths only

Comment: ah ok , last edit was neccessary then :) OK than your url is probably wrong.. try to solution that i will mention on my answer.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are searching for this:

```
String fullPath = "/data/data/" + this.getPackageName() + "/" + path;
            File dir = new File(fullPath);
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdir();
```